# how to resolve git conflict file

Tags: git

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
asd
||||||| merged common ancestors
=======g
test
>>>>>>> b0acaed6842e69ac407029e0f580b54b64258980
<<<<<<< HEAD


test312
||||||| merged common ancestors
=======

asdfdfsfdsafdadfasd
>>>>>>> 6d92ab6b31d03c5c13803eca25762b4fb273a0c5
```

A sample scenario of git conflict. How to clean or fix the **`<<<<<<< HEAD`** and **`>>>>>>> 6d92ab6b31d03c5c13803eca25762b4fb273a0c5`** on the file.

Comment: You can use a merge strategies to choose which change you want to use (`ours`, `their` etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These is the output of a `diff3` (and not `diff2`).
You can control how you want it to be displayed using `merge.conflictstyle`.

> ***`merge.conflictStyle`***
>
> Specify the style in which conflicted hunks are written out to working tree files upon merge.
>
> The default is `merge`, which shows a <<<<<<< conflict marker, changes made by one side, a ======= marker, changes made by the other side, and then a >>>>>>> marker.
>
> **An alternate style, `diff3`, adds a ||||||| marker and the original text before the ======= marker.**

You simply need to edit the file, fix it the way you want and commit.

```
vi <file name>

# Fix the error in the file
# add the file and commit it
git add .

# no need to supply message, it will have the Merge message automatically
git commit
```

Answer (score 0):

The markers simply indicate where the merge conflicts are within the file.  Resolve the merge conflict manually in your editor of choice deleting the merge marker lines starting with <<<<<<< and ======= as you go .

Once you're done save the file, **run your tests** and commit the change(s).

Always a good idea to grep the repo for any additional merge markers too.

Comment: No.  There are two conflicting changes to the file so there is no reliable way git or a third party merge tool could decide what you'd like to keep.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually remove the conflicts. There is no automated method, as per my knowledge.
Then use the command `git commit -i filename` from command prompt.
Then ESC: wq
Then `git push origin <branchname>`